# Insurance problem

Tags: probability, actuarial-science

The following is the type of problem that I am dealing with.

> An insurer makes $n=4$ driving errors, each independently resulting in an accident with probability $p=.3$.  Each accident results in a loss which is exponentially distributed with mean 0.5.  Losses are mutually independent and independent of the number of accidents. The insurance company pays 70% of each loss due to an accident. Calculate the variance of the total unreinbursed loss the insurer experiences due to accidents resulting from these driving errors.

So far this is what I understand.

1), The driving errors are independent from each other will the same probability, so I know that this is a binomial distribution with $n=4$ and $p=.3$.  So if $N$ represents the number of errors made, $$E[N]=np=1.2, \space Var[N]=npq=.84$$

2), The loss is independent from the number of accidents, so simply each accident will result in a loss with pdf $$f(x)=\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{-x}{2}}$$ where $X$ represents the amount of loss given an accident.  $$E[X]=\frac{1}{2}, \space Var[x]=\frac{1}{4}$$

3), Letting $Y$ the amount paid by the insurance company, I know that $$E[Y]=.7E[X], \space$Var[Y]=.49Var[X]$$ due to independence.

So, the thing that I want to deal with the amount the insurer will not get paid, and I want to say $X-Y$ so I am looking for $$Var[X-Y]=Var[X]+Var[Y]$$ which does not give me the right answer.

So it would be most helpful if these questions were included in the explanation.

a), I am having trouble seeing how the number of accidents comes into play for this problem.

b), The book uses a formula that kind of looks like $$Var[E[X|S]]+E[Var[X|S]]=E[S]$$
and I would like to know more about this.  So can you lead me to where I can understand this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula your book is using is called the [Law of Total Variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance).

Also, assuming you are interested in the total amount the insurance company is out, you want to look at the total amount they have to pay, which is 
$Y = \sum_{i=1}^N 0.7 X_i$ where $X_i$ is the loss amount of the $i^{th}$ accident. Notice that this is a mixture process. Note that for $k$ fixed $\sum_{i=1}^k X_i$ has a Gamma($k,\lambda$) distribution:
$$
  {\bf E}\left[ \sum_{i=1}^k X_i \right]
= k \lambda, \ \ 
  Var\left[ \sum_{i=1}^k X_i \right]
= k\lambda^2.
$$
 Then
$$
  {\bf E}[Y]
= 0.7{\bf E}\left[{\bf E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \mid N \right] \right]
= 0.7 {\bf E}[N \lambda]
= 0.7\lambda np
$$
and 
\begin{align}
   Var[Y]
&= Var[{\bf E}[Y \mid N]] + {\bf E}[Var[Y \mid N]] \\
&= Var\left[0.7{\bf E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \mid N \right] \right] + 
   {\bf E}\left[0.7^2 Var\left[\sum_{i=1}^N X_i \mid N \right]\right] \\
&= Var[0.7 N \lambda] + {\bf E}[0.7^2 N \lambda^2] \\
&= 0.7^2 \lambda^2 (Var[N] + {\bf E}[N ] ) \\
&= 0.7^2 \lambda^2 (npq + np ) \\
&= 0.7^2 \lambda^2 np(q + 1 ).
\end{align}

Comment: That was actually very helpful, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!